# How to check if a proc has syntax errors before executing it in tclsh

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I have defined a proc in tclsh

```
proc abs {x} {
  if {$x > 0} { 
    puts "111" 
  } else if {$x = 0} {
    puts "222"
  } else {
    puts "333
  }
}
```

When defining this proc, tclsh did not detect my syntax error until it was reported during execution.

```
tclsh8.5 % abs 1
wrong # args: extra words after "else" clause in "if" command
while evaluating {abs 1}
```

How to check the syntax of this proc before executing it？

Answer (score 2):

One tool to detect syntax errors in Tcl scripts is https://nagelfar.sourceforge.net/

Some others are listed at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Static+syntax+analysis#95329c336da897c3dea8ab434ca30575f4529bf6f514c1519881bd126e1d1423